# For Loop wait and delay - Swift 4

Tags: swift, for-loop, delay, wait

I have a nested for loop, and am trying to make it so that the outer loop will only continue once the inner loop and its code is completed, and also add a 1 second delay before performing the next loop.

```
    for _ in 0...3 {
        for player in 0...15 {
            // CODE ADDING MOVEMENTS TO QUEUE
        }
        updateBoardArray()
        printBoard()

        // NEED TO WAIT HERE FOR 1 SEC
    }
```

So I wan't the 0...3 For loop to progress only once the inner loop and update and print functions have completed their cycle, and also a 1 second wait time.

At the moment it all happens at once and then just prints all 4 boards instantly, even when I put that 1 second wait in using DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {}.

Have tried other answers to similar questions but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I understand, what you tried to do is the following:

```
for _ in 0...3 {
   for player in 0...15 {
     // CODE ADDING MOVEMENTS TO QUEUE
   }

   updateBoardArray()
   printBoard()

   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {}
}
```

This will **NOT** work since what you are doing is add a task (that will do nothing) to the main queue that will get trigged after 1 second, and after adding it, the code continues with the for, without waiting.

**Solution**

What you could do is simply use `sleep(1)`, but bear in mind that this will freeze the main thread (if you are executing this in the main thread).

To avoid freezing the app you could do is:

```
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
       for _ in 0...3 {
            for player in 0...15 {
                // CODE ADDING MOVEMENTS TO QUEUE
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                updateBoardArray()
                printBoard()
            }

            sleep(1)

            }
        } 
   }
```

Just keep in mind that any UI action you do, must be done in the main thread

Comment: Awesome stuff. Exactly what I needed too.

Answer (score 5):

`asyncAfter()` function takes `DispatchTime`. `DispatchTime` is in nanosecond. Following is prototype:

```
func asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime, execute: DispatchWorkItem)
```

Following is extract of [docs from Apple Developer webpage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300020-asyncafter):

> DispatchTime represents a point in time relative to the default clock with nanosecond precision. On Apple platforms, the default clock is based on the Mach absolute time unit

To solve the problem, use:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1000) {}
```

Comment: It's clearer now to use `.now() + .seconds(1)`. Otherwise it's easy to get confused about what "1000" means.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scheduledTimer:

```
for i in 0..3{
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2 * Double(i), repeats: false) { (timer) in
        //CODE
    }
}
```

More Info about [scheduledTimer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer).